# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearStorage') - NextJs

Tags: next.js, local-storage, zustand

In my NextJs component, I am using Zustand persist for localstorage in browsers.

and I use a Shadcn UI button below, but NextJs shows errors below in my terminal:

```
components/stateInput.tsx (40:75) @ clearStorage
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearStorage')
```

```js
<Button className='destructive-color' onClick={useItemsStore.persist.clearStorage}>Clear Storage</Button>
```

I tried to use

```js
const clearStorage = (): void => {
    useItemsStore.persist.clearStorage();
}
...
<Button className='destructive-color' onClick={clearStorage}>Clear Storage</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it works

```js
const clearStorage = (): void => {
    useItemsStore.persist.clearStorage();
}
```

after restarting NextJs, wait for a few seconds, then refresh the page... then maybe restart NextJs again...

Hopefully, NextJs can run faster next time...